# Can I influence the force at D3.js so that a "nice" net is created?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The picture 'is/should'-image describes very well what I mean by that. 
[image]

I show with to build a network with d3.js. Unfortunately, force seems to place the nodes randomly. How can I influence that?

The goal is that there are so few floods in the lines as possible.

My force-obj I create this way:

```
    var force = window.d3.layout.force()      
      .charge(-1500)
      .linkStrength(90)      
      .linkDistance(10)      
      .friction(0.5)      
      .chargeDistance("Infinity") 
      .theta(0.8) 
      .gravity(0.05)
      .on("tick",this.dotick);
```